# Coffescript compile constructor with wrong argument name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm trying to use for the first time Coffeescript with AngularJS.

I want to define a new service with a dependence with the service `$http`

Here Is what I'm expecting:

```
var MyService = function($http) {
    this.$http = $http;
};

MyService.prototype.call = function(url, data) {
  this.$http(url, data);
};

myApp.service("webService", MyService)
```

This the normal way to register a service as shown in the AngularJS documentation.

After reading an article about working with Coffeescript and AngularJS, I have tried this:

```
myApp.service "webService", class
    constructor : (@$http) ->
    call : (url, data) -> @$http url, data
```

But the result of the compilation give this javascript:

```
myApp.service("webService", (function() {
    function _Class(_at_$http) {
        this.$http = _at_$http;
    }

    _Class.prototype.call = function(url, data) {
        return this.$http(url, data);
    };

    return _Class;

})());
```

The problem is that the Coffeescript compiler shouldn't replace `@$http` by `_at_$http`. In my case it should output this javascript:

```
myApp.service("webService", (function() {
    function _Class($http) {
        this.$http = $http;
    }

    _Class.prototype.call = function(url, data) {
        return this.$http(url, data);
    };

    return _Class;

})());
```

You can view that [online compiler on Coffeescript website](http://coffeescript.org/#try:thresholdApp.service%20%22webService%22%2C%0A%09class%0A%09%09constructor%20%3A%20(%40%24http)%20-%3E%0A%0A%09%09%23%20Private%0A%09%09baseUrl%20%3D%20%22%22%0A%09%09protocol%20%3D%20%22%22%0A%09%09init%20%3D%20-%3E%0A%09%09%09protocol%20%3D%20if%20afs.ssl%20then%20%22http%3A%2F%2F%22%20else%20%22https%3A%2F%2F%22%0A%09%09%09baseUrl%20%3D%20protocol%20%2B%20afs.cloudHost%20%2B%20%22%2F%22%20%2B%20afs.session.token%20%2B%20%22%2F%22%0A%0A%09%09get%20%3D%20(url%2C%20callback%2C%20errorCallback)%20-%3E%0A%09%09%09init()%0A%09%09%09%40%24http.get%20baseUrl%20%2B%20url%0A%09%09%09.success%20(result)%20-%3E%0A%09%09%09%09if%20result.result%20then%20callback%20result%0A%09%09%09%09else%0A%09%09%09%09%09if%20result.code%20is%20102%20then%20%40logout%20(-%3E)%2C%20errorCallback%20%23%20Authentification%20error%0A%09%09%09%09%09else%20errorCallback%20result.code%2C%20result.error%0A%09%09%09.error%20(data%2C%20status%2C%20headers%2C%20config)%20-%3E%0A%09%09%09%09log%20data%3B%20log%20status%3B%20log%20headers%3B%20log%20config%0A%09%09%09%09errorCallback%20%22Error%22%2C%20%22Error%22%0A%0A%0A%09%09post%20%3D%20(token%2C%20url%2C%20data%2C%20callback%2C%20errorCallback)%20-%3E%0A%09%09%09init()%0A%09%09%09%40%24http.post%20baseUrl%20%2B%20url%2C%20data%0A%09%09%09.success%20(result)%20-%3E%0A%09%09%09%09if%20result.result%20then%20callback%20result%0A%09%09%09%09else%0A%09%09%09%09%09if%20result.code%20is%20102%20then%20%40logout%20(-%3E)%2C%20errorCallback%20%23%20Authentification%20error%0A%09%09%09%09%09else%20errorCallback%20result.code%2C%20result.error%0A%09%09%09.error%20(data%2C%20status%2C%20headers%2C%20config)%20-%3E%0A%09%09%09%09log%20data%3B%20log%20status%3B%20log%20headers%3B%20log%20config%0A%09%09%09%09errorCallback%20%22Error%22%2C%20%22Error%22%0A%0A%09%09del%20%3D%20(token%2C%20url%2C%20callback%2C%20errorCallback)%20-%3E%0A%09%09%09init()%0A%09%09%09%40%24http.delete%20baseUrl%20%2B%20url%0A%09%09%09.success%20(result)%20-%3E%0A%09%09%09%09if%20result.result%20then%20callback%20result%0A%09%09%09%09else%0A%09%09%09%09%09if%20result.code%20is%20102%20then%20%40logout%20(-%3E)%2C%20errorCallback%20%23%20Authentification%20error%0A%09%09%09%09%09else%20errorCallback%20result.code%2C%20result.error%0A%09%09%09.error%20(data%2C%20status%2C%20headers%2C%20config)%20-%3E%0A%09%09%09%09log%20data%3B%20log%20status%3B%20log%20headers%3B%20log%20config%0A%09%09%09%09errorCallback%20%22Error%22%2C%20%22Error%22%0A%0A%09%09login%20%3A%20(callback%20%3D%20(-%3E)%2C%20errorCallback%20%3D%20(code%2C%20error)-%3E%20alert%20%22Erreur%20%23%7Bcode%7D%20%3A%20%23%7Berror%7D%22)%20-%3E%0A%09%09%09init()%0A%09%09%09if%20afs.session.expiration%20%3E%3D%20(new%20Date()).getTime()%20%2B%205000%0A%0A%09%09%09%09callabck()%3B%20return%0A%0A%09%09%09%40%24http.post%20protocol%20%2B%20afs.cloudHost%20%2B%20%22%2Flogin%22%2C%0A%09%09%09%09login%3A%20afs.login%0A%09%09%09%09password%3A%20afs.password%0A%09%09%09%09store%3A%20afs.idStore%0A%09%09%09.success%20(result)%20-%3E%0A%09%09%09%09if%20result.result%0A%09%09%09%09%09afs.session.token%20%3D%20result.token%0A%09%09%09%09%09afs.session.expiration%20%3D%20result.expiration%0A%09%09%09%09%09callback%20result.token%0A%09%09%09%09else%20errorCallback%20result.code%2C%20result.error%0A%09%09%09%09return%0A%09%09%09.error%20(data%2C%20status%2C%20headers%2C%20config)%20-%3E%0A%09%09%09%09log%20data%3B%20log%20status%3B%20log%20headers%3B%20log%20config%0A%09%09%09%09errorCallback%20%22Error%22%2C%20%22Error%22%0A%0A%09%09logout%20%3A%20(callback%20%3D%20(-%3E)%2C%20errorCallback%20%3D%20(code%2C%20error)-%3E%20alert%20%22Erreur%20%23%7Bcode%7D%20%3A%20%23%7Berror%7D%22)%20-%3E%0A%09%09%09init()%0A%09%09%09if%20afs.session.expiration%20%3C%3D%20(new%20Date()).getTime()%20then%20callabck()%3B%20return%0A%0A%09%09%09%40%24http.get%20baseUrl%20%2B%20%22logout%22%0A%09%09%09.success%20(result)%20-%3E%0A%09%09%09%09if%20result.result%0A%09%09%09%09%09afs.session.expiration%20%3D%200%0A%09%09%09%09%09afs.session.token%20%3D%20%22%22%0A%09%09%09%09%09callback()%0A%09%09%09%09else%0A%09%09%09%09%09if%20data.code%20is%20102%20%23Authentification%20error%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09afs.session.expiration%20%3D%200%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09afs.session.token%20%3D%20%22%22%0A%09%09%09%09%09errorCallback%20result.code%2C%20result.error%0A%09%09%09.error%20(data%2C%20status%2C%20headers%2C%20config)%20-%3E%0A%09%09%09%09log%20data%3B%20log%20status%3B%20log%20headers%3B%20log%20config%0A%09%09%09%09errorCallback%20%22Error%22%2C%20%22Error%22%0A%0A%09%09get%20%3A%20(url%2C%20callback%20%3D%20(-%3E)%2C%20errorCallback%20%3D%20(code%2C%20error)-%3E%20alert%20%22Erreur%20%23%7Bcode%7D%20%3A%20%23%7Berror%7D%22)%20-%3E%0A%09%09%09%40login%20((token%20%3D%20afs.session.token)%20-%3E%20get%20token%2C%20url%2C%20callback%2C%20errorCallback)%2C%20errorCallback%0A%0A%09%09post%20%3A%20(url%2C%20data%2C%20callback%20%3D%20(-%3E)%2C%20errorCallback%20%3D%20(code%2C%20error)-%3E%20alert%20%22Erreur%20%23%7Bcode%7D%20%3A%20%23%7Berror%7D%22)%20-%3E%0A%09%09%09%40login%20((token%20%3D%20afs.session.token)%20-%3E%20post%20token%2C%20url%2C%20data%2C%20callback%2C%20errorCallback)%2C%20errorCallback%0A%0A%09%09delete%20%3A%20(url%2C%20callback%20%3D%20(-%3E)%2C%20errorCallback%20%3D%20(code%2C%20error)-%3E%20alert%20%22Erreur%20%23%7Bcode%7D%20%3A%20%23%7Berror%7D%22)%20-%3E%0A%09%09%09%40login%20((token%20%3D%20afs.session.token)%20-%3E%20del%20token%2C%20url%2C%20callback%2C%20errorCallback)%2C%20errorCallback%0A) give that expected result, so I don't understand why mine is not working well.

And I need this because of angular injection engine not recognize `_at_$http` because it expect `$http` parameter name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade to [CoffeeScript 1.9.1 or higher](http://coffeescript.org/#changelog):

> - Internal compiler variable names no longer start with underscores. This makes the generated JavaScript a bit prettier, and also fixes an issue with the completely broken and ungodly way that AngularJS "parses" function arguments.

If you can't upgrade then you could hook up the instance variable by hand:

```
constructor : ($http) -> @$http = $http
```

Everything works fine for you at [CoffeeScript.org](http://coffeescript.org) because they're always running the latest version.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I haven't got thé idea to check coffescript updates ^^